# Cómo podría integrar las notificaciones push en Ionic 3

Tags: firebase, typescript, push-notification, ionic3

Me encargaron crear una función que actualice cada 5 minutos la app para buscar los camiones de basura cercanos en un radio de 2 kilómetros y si encuentra uno cerca que mande una notificación push al usuario.

Estuve jugando un poco con la documentación de Firebase pero solo he podido enviar notificaciones desde el panel de admin de Firebase.

La idea es como Uber, que si hay un carro cerca, te mande una notificación push a tu celular.

¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto posible?

Comment: Hommy De Jesús, bienvenido. Te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), ya que tu problema como está planteado es demasiado amplio. Deberías investigar un poco y plantear problemas puntuales para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia. Es que estoy implementando una nueva función a una app que ya está realizada. Solo he podido enviar notificaciones desde Firebase. Quisiera poder crear una función que actualizara cada 5 minutos y buscara los carros cerca y mandara una notificación al usuario.

Comment: Eso es en typescript